# Displaying WordPress page number/count in relation to siblings

Tags: wordpress, count, wordpress-theming

I want to add a page number to a part on my page. Something like *7 of 22*. I've found a ton of ways to do something similar to this, but not quite this...

First, this is for Pages, not Posts. Secondly, this will be in the sidebar. The second number must be the total number of sibling pages and the first number should be the current page's position from menu_order.

What's the easiest way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I doubt you'll find an easier way to do this. Do this not work? if it did, please click the check-mark and except my answer as correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's an easy way that will work in your sidebar:

```
<?php
        $page_id = $post->ID;
        $page_parent = $post->post_parent;
        if ($page_parent) { // there's a parent page, get the children
            $args = array(
                'parent' => $page_parent,
                'child_of' => $page_parent,
                'hierarchical' => 0,
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
            );
        }
        else { // no parent, so just get top level pages
            $args = array(
                'parent' => 0,
                'sort_column' => 'menu_order'
            );
        }
        $my_pages = get_pages($args);
        while ($page = current($my_pages)) { // find this page's position in the page array
            if ($page->ID == $page_id) {
                echo key($my_pages) + 1;
            }
            next($my_pages);
        }
        $result = count($my_pages);
        echo " of " . $result;
    ?>
```